# Specify email address in SendEmail event

Tags: javascript, email

I have done my research on the Google SendEmail tutorial as well as some modifications that have been presented on this site for activating the email based on data matching criteria.

What I want to do is have the email sent if the data doesn't match the current date instead of the original code that was posted on this site which sent if it did match.

I believe I have everything set correctly but I don't want to use an email address from the spreadsheet, I want the email to go to a specific email address every time and would like to be able to input that email address into the code.

I have already set the trigger up as a timed event to run daily, just need the email address in the Email Address section resolved and then I can test. 
If anyone sees anything else I've set up that you believe won't work please let me know, below is the code as I currently have it set up.

Thanks

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row[26]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-0700','yyyy:MM:dd')
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT-0700', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
    Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate > SsheetDate){
      var emailAddress = "myemail@testemail.com";  
      var subject = "Data Not Updated";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject);
     Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject)
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to figure out how to make this work: If anyone sees any potential issues with this code please let me know

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var youremail     = "Randy.Bach@boydgroup.com";
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row[26]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-0700','yyyy:MM:dd')
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT-0700', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
    Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate > SsheetDate){
      var emailaddress = youremail; 
      var subject = "Data Not Updated";
      var message = "Data failed to load";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, subject, message);
     Logger.log('SENT :'+emailaddress+'  '+subject+' '+message)
    }    
  }
}
```